# Was there any particular reason the 6502's LDX#imm and LDY#imm aren't opcodes A8 and AA?

Tags: history, 6502

Parts of the 6502 opcode map are fairly regular, and parts of it aren't.  One bit that strikes me as really weird is the decoding of LD_ instructions, in relation to the decoding of other ALU instructions.

In general, opcodes of the form xxxMMM01 or 10xMMMxx use addressing mode MMM, where mode 010 is immediate.  While processing 100010xx in that fashion would not be terribly useful [the pattern would suggest they should be ST_ #imm], processing 101010xx in that fashion would seem like the most straightforward way of handling LDY #imm and LDX #imm.  Curiously, though, those opcodes get mapped to TAY and TAX instructions, requiring LDY #imm and LDX #imm to be moved to opcodes 10100000 and 10100010.

Did anything in the 6502's hardware make it easier to disable the "load-immediate" sequencing for "101010x0" but enable it for "101000x0", while making the former instruction output the accumulator on the internal bus from which X and Y are latched, than to simply put "LDX #imm" and "LDY #imm" next to "LDA #imm" in a fashion similar to all the other supported operand forms?

Answer (score 9):

All of the instructions that use the A register and an immediate operand use an encoding matching the pattern of `xxx01001`.  The rest of the immediate instructions use either X or Y as the register and are in the pattern `1xx000x0`.  All opcodes that fit either of these patterns use immediates or are undefined.

On the other hand, TAY and TAX are grouped together with other instructions that have an implied operand, including the shift instructions that use the A register, all matching the pattern `xxxx10x0`.  This pattern doesn't include all implied instructions, but all opcodes that match this pattern either have implied operands, shift the A register, or are undefined.

So the position of LDY immediate and LDX immediate opcodes doesn't seem weird to me, they're off in their own section of the opcode table separate from the immediate instructions that use the A register. Similarly TAX and TAY are in the section of the opcode table with other similar instructions.

To put it another way, the pattern you've noticed only works for opcodes that match the pattern `xxxMMM01`. It doesn't work for `10xMMMxx` where `MMM` is `010` because none of the `xxx01000` and `xxx01010` opcodes use immediates, only the `xxx01001` opcodes do.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, though opcodes that match the "immediate XY" pattern end up being inconsistent with regard to how they select X or Y.  I would think it would have been easier to say that everything of the form 00xxxxxx is a single-byte instruction, and everything else has its format determined by three of the remaining bits.  Use the encodings for eight of what would otherwise be store-immediate or read-modify-write immediate instructions for branches (or use all nine and add unconditional branch), and three otherwise-unused opcodes that would include a two-byte address for...

Comment: ...jmp, indirect-jmp, and maybe jsr.  Such a design approach may be easier when looking at a whole instruction set than it would be if the instruction set was being designed concurrently with the hardware.  I wonder what the actual design approach was?

Answer (score 7):

> Parts of the 6502 opcode map are fairly regular, and parts of it aren't. One bit that strikes me as really weird is the decoding of LD_ instructions, in relation to the decoding of other ALU instructions.

Well, for one, **`LDX`/`LDY` do not use the ALU**, but more importantly, the way you decode it is a bit off. See below for a more detailed view on the 6500 encoding.

The `LDX`/`LDY` immediate encoding is fine. The quirk within the transfer instructions is at `TYA` which is `98` instead of `88`. And there is no technical reson why it has been done that way. There are similar other encodings, especially around the increment/decrement for the index registers.

---

### 6500 Opcode encoding

The format isn't built the way you assume. While the general structure follows a 3-3-2 stucture like

```
aaa-bbb-tt
```

reading it requires to start at the end with

```
tt defining an instruction group
```

This is even visible the way the decoder hardware is done, as tt is not taken as seperate bits like all others, but turned into 3 lines for the three groups used, thus being the primary differentiation for all decoding.

(To simplify this, lets push group 0 (tt=`00`) to the end.)

- **Group 1 (tt=`01`)** is the most simple. Here `aaa` selects one of 8 instructions (`ORA`, `AND`, `EOR`, `ADC`, `STA`, `LDA`, `CMP`, `SBC`) and `bbb` defines an addressing mode (`(ZP,X)`, `ZP`, `IMM`, `ABS`, `(ZP),Y`, `ZP,X`, `ABS,Y`, `ABS,X`). Drawing this up(*1) will give a filled table with one empty spot at `89`, where the nonsensical `STA IMM` would end up (*2).
- **Group 2 (tt=`10`)** uses a similar encoding with `aaa` as instruction and `bbb` as addressing, just with different opcodes (`ASL`, `ROL`, `LSR`, `ROR`, `STX`, `LDX`, `DEC`, `INC`) and some addressing rearranged (`IMM` replacing `(ZP,X)` and `ACC` `IMM`) or not used (`IMM`, `ZP`, `ACC`, `ABS`, na, `ZP,X`/`ZP,Y`, na, `ABS,X`/`ABS,Y`). Here the `STX A` and `LDX A` are occupied exactly by `TXA` and `TAX`. Similarly, the 'unused' addressing `110` is used with `STX`/`LDX` to form `TXS` and `TSX`.

  Group 2 is also the point where they started to screw it up, as `9E`, where `STX ABS,Y` should be, is left out. And while the logical position for `DEC A` is filled by `DEX`, and `NOP` resides where a `INC A` could be (*3).
- **Group 3 (tt=`11`)** is the most simple of all, as it doesn't exist :))
- **Group 0 (tt=`00`)** finally is where it gets crowded. At first it's much like group 2. The instructions are now  (na, `BIT`, na, na, `STY`, `LDY`, `CPY`, `CPX`) while the general addressing modes are the same as with group 2 plus `REL` and `FLAG`(`IMM`, `ZP`, `ACC`, `ABS`, `REL`, `ZP,X`, `FLAG`, `ABS,X`).

So far everything is regular, group 0 holds the remaining instructions as well, sprinkled in in a less than regular way:

Addressing `REL` now overwrites (in a table for group 0) the instruction with `BRx` and `FLAG` with flag manipulation - with the exception, that `CLV` ended up where `SEV` would be if it existed - and `TYA` taking up its space.

Similarly, the stack operations lie diagonally to the encoding - and again `TAY` is screwing up the somewhat regular placement of increment/decrement for the index registers.

`JMP` does follow the scheme in so far as the `01x.011.00` encoding used the `ABS` addressing.

The remaining instructions (`BRK`, `JSR`, `RTI`, `RTS`) fall completely out of context. But they show at least some inherent logic, especially when considering that `BRK` is internally fed into the decoder also whenever a hardware interrupt occurs.

---

*1 - Drawing tables on SE sucks - so please use your imagination.

*2 - A hole filled up by the 65C02 with `BIT IMM`, since the 'rightful' spot `20` was taken by the irregular `JSR`.

*3 - as a result the 65C02 had to put `INC A`/`DEC A` onto new places.

Comment: I think you mean `20` was taken up by `JSR`.

Comment: I guess what puzzles me is why instructions of the form `1iimmmxa` where `xa` isn't `00` weren't interpreted as `[st/ld/cp/??][axy]` with "normal" addressing mode `mmm`, which would have eliminated the need to do anything special with them.  There's plenty of room elsewhere in the opcode map (including the entire group 11) to accommodate anything else that would conflict with such decoding, and decoding instructions that are of the form `1iimmmxa` but not `1XXXXX00` in such fashion would have eliminated the need for all other decoding logic associated with ldx/ldy/stx/sty/cpx/cpy.

Comment: @supercat, I think you may be making the same mistake as many others, that the bit positions somehow indicate the operation to be carried out. That would be so with a simple gate-based decoder but the 6502 used a lookup table on the T-state and a majority of the opcode, and the lookup table itself dictated which "micro-actions" took place. That allowed for arbitrarily complex mappings from bits to actions.

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* want to understand why things were the way they were on the 6502, I'd suggest looking into [27c3: Reverse Engineering the MOS 6502 CPU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWqBmmPQP40) on YouTube (or search for that text if the video ever disappears).

Starting at about 25 minutes into the video (but I urge you to watch the whole thing), it details the impressive work of Greg James, Barry and Brian Silverman and Ed Spittles, in deconstructing the inner workings of the 6502. This involved the use of hot acid to remove the plastic, taking *massively* high resolution photos of the chip at multiple layers, splicing them together, and analysing and debugging all the tracks.

The end result of all that hard work can be found at [visual6502.org](http://visual6502.org/). This isn't your garden-variety 6502 emulator that does what the opcode map says it should do. No, *this* emulator reaches into the guts of the 6502 internal hardware (the transistors and electrical signals) to accurately perform the same operations as the original chip.

But the important information is still in the video at about 34.5 minutes in, in part III.

In this section based on the Visual6502 work, the presenter details how the 6502 logic works in terms of the T-states (timing states) and opcodes to control the individual bits of hardware *within* the 6502. Basically, the CPU uses a decode ROM to translate these two inputs into a series of outputs which cause other bits of hardware (via a "random control logic" controller) to weave their magic.

And it's *this* driving of the other hardware bits which shows why certain operations exist at specific opcodes and what the outcome is of using the roughly 40% of unused opcodes.

Any further description I could give would be inadequate next to the presentation, it does a *great* job of ripping apart the mystique. Seriously, go and watch the video.

In terms of your *specific* question:

> Did anything in the 6502's hardware make it easier to disable the "load-immediate" sequencing for "101010x0" but enable it for "101000x0"?

The answer is yes. The decode ROM (which you will hopefully understand once you've seen the video) looked at the top six bits of the opcode and used that to select which internal operation sets were carried out in each T-state.

So, in all honesty, they could have been two *totally* different operations (such as `LDA` and `NOP`, all it would have taken was a slightly modified decode ROM.

Your contention that "opcodes of the form xxxMMM01 or 10xMMMxx use addressing mode MMM, where mode 010 is immediate" is valid only if you assume very simple interpretation of the bit values in an opcode. The presence of the decode ROM makes the interpretation able to be arbitrarily complex.

Comment: I would have expected that it would have been easiest to say that if either of the top two bits of the opcode is set, the bottom three bits will identify one of eight addressing modes.  The CPU would then spend the next 1-5 cycles computing an address and fetching a value from there except that some store instructions would skip the fetch.  Then the CPU would either do a modify and/or write cycle if needed, and an instruction fetch.

Comment: By my count, there are six instructions that simply load a value and latch a result into A, six that simply load a value but don't write the result to A (one examines X, one examines Y, one latches X, and one latches Y), three that simply write, and six that do read-modify-write.  Supporting all eight addressing modes for the first 12, and seven for the remaining nine would seem simpler than having different instructions support different combinations of addressing modes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers the question, but this page has some very good tables that break down the 6502 instruction layout:

https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html

Scroll down to "Appendix C: 6502 Instruction Layout" for several pivoted charts of instructions laid out by a,b,c with this description:

> The 6502 instruction table is laid out according to a pattern a-b-c,
>   where a and b are an octal number each, followed by a group of two
>   binary digits c, as in the bit-vector "aaabbbcc".
>
> Example: All ROR instructions share a = 3 and c = 2 with the address
>   mode in b (3x2). At the same time, all instructions addressing the
>   zero-page share b = 1 (x1x). abc = 312  =>  (3 << 5 | 1 << 2 | 2)  = 
>   $66, ROR zpg.
>
> Notably, there are no legal opcodes defined where c = 3, accounting
>   for the empty columns in the usual, hexadecimal view of the
>   instruction table.
>
> The following table lists the instruction set, rows sorted by c, then
>   a.
>
> Generally, instructions of a kind are typically found in rows as a
>   combination of a and c, and address modes are in columns b. However,
>   there are a few exception to this rule, namely, where bits 0 of both c
>   and b are low (c = 0, 2; b = 0, 2, 4, 6) and combinations of c and b
>   select a group of related operations. (E.g., c=0 ∧ b=4: branch, c=0 ∧
>   b=6: set flag)

Comment: That kind of table is what raises the question, rather than answering it.  In the last table on the page, all of the odd columns show "LDY/LDA/LDX" in the three rows where a==6.  My question is why that same pattern wasn't equally applied to the even columns.

Comment: If you take a look at the first of the three tables at the bottom in Appendix C, and look at the section where b=2, c=1, there are a collection of instructions with immediate addressing. There is one open slot, but three more immediate instructions which I would guess is why they are mapped to b=0, c=0, a=5, 6, & 7.

Comment: Laying things out so that the sequence of memory addresses accessed by iiiaaaqq would always be specified by aaa unless qq is 00 would have simplified instruction decoding, especially if, instead of having the instruction sequencer count states in order, it jumped to a "probably have memory address" or "definitely have memory address" state once effective-address logic was complete.  That would allow the same logic to be used for the third through fifth cycles of "inc zp" as for the fifth through seventh of "inc abs,x".

Comment: Since there are fewer than 24 non-branching instructions that use a non-implied addressing mode, and fewer than 64 other instructions, there's enough opcode space to allocate eight opcodes to each non-branching instruction that offers any non-implied addressing modes.  The placement of some implied-addressing-mode instructions conflicts with that, but there's room for all such instructions in the qq=11 part of the table (if one wants to make BRK be 00, grab qq from the inverted side of the instruction-latch bits).